# Why can't I do a .split() on a string with a space in it with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm having a hard time getting the `.split()` function to work when the string by which it's being split has spaces or any characters other than simple letters or numbers in it.  I've tried escaping them with backslash notation, but it's not working.  The code below doesn't supply a second item in the resulting array.

```
function isGoodSerp(kw, optResults, optTld, optStart) {
  errorOccurred = false;
  kw = kw || "office 365";
  optResults = optResults || 10;
  optStart = optStart || 0;
  optTld = optTld || '.com';
  try {
    var url = 'http://www.google' + optTld + '/search?q=' + kw + '&start=' + optStart + '&num=' + optResults;
    var fullHtml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var noHeaderHtml = fullHtml.split("Search Results");
    Logger.log("noHeaderHtml" + noHeaderHtml[1]);

  } catch(e) {
    errorOccurred = true;
    return e;
  }
}
```

Comment: The page source does show that it's in there, and only once. [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=wkja&oq=wkja&gs_l=serp.3..0i10j0j0i30l2j0i10i30j0i30j0i10i30.3941.5165.0.5477.7.7.0.0.0.0.112.546.6j1.7.0....0...1.1.64.serp..6.1.112.gkK2KIT81Mo)

Comment: I don't think you are using the split function properly, except there's more to your code. because the .split() works by checking if what you pass inside into .split("STRING") exists inside the appended string. [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

So basically what you are saying is, it should check for where "Search Results exists in fullHtml

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just pull out the actual search results and check for a certain term within them, but the Xml class has been deprecated and its replacement doesn't have the proper functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the text you want to split with does not exists in the resulting page (as Babajide Fowotade already stated). Thus the result is a single element with the complete `fullHtml`-content.

Example:

```
console.log(("test").split('XXX'));
```

results in `["test"]`.

I don't know what you are trying to reach. There is no text "Search results" in the google search results page - at least not if I use it...

Split is working by searching for the text you provide and return the text "around".

Example:

```
console.log(("this is a test").split(' '));
```

results in `["this", "is", "a", "test"]`.

Comment: When I search on Google, within the page source, I see this `<h2 class="hd">Search Results</h2>` right above the search results.  It doesn't show as a visible element, though.  Maybe it's not something that is there every time.  I'll try splitting on a different string.

Comment: @JoelSexton: Ah, now I see it! **But it's still not in the source of the page!** The headlines are generated by javascript, and you don't execute any JavaScript of the page. You have to deal with the plain HTML source that the server sends (right click on the page, "show source").
Alternatively, you can use PhantomJS or a similar headless browser..

Besides that, the text is language dependent (maybe sufficient, but not the best choice).